# Microsoft Graph: Get delta on shared mail folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If I (my.user@example.com  = logged in user) try to get a delta on a mail folder another user (other.user@example.com) shares with me...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/other.user@example.com/mailFolders/OtherUsersInboxFolderId==/messages/microsoft.graph.delta?$filter=ReceivedDateTime%20ge%202021-04-01T08:00:00.0000000Z
```

... I get an ErrorItemNotFound:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-19T10:00:00",
            "request-id": "<GUID>",
            "client-request-id": "<GUID>"
        }
    }
}
```

If I do not request a delta but simply the messages in that folder, the request succeeds and returns the expected messages:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/other.user@example.com/mailFolders/OtherUsersInboxFolderId==/messages
```

If I (my.user@example.com) try to get a delta for the Inbox folder of a shared mailbox (shared@example.com), the request also succeeds:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/shared@example.com/mailFolders/SharedUsersInboxFolderId==/messages
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-a-shared-mailbox?view=o365-worldwide

So now my question is:
Why do deltas not work on folders another user shares with me?
Is it simply not implemented in the Graph API or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see the same behavior, it is weird that I `.../message` works fine while `../message/delta` does not. I am not sure if this is not supported or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Delta call is not supported on a shared mail folder and that is why you get 404.